# Simple formula for map from positive integers to ones and twos?

Tags: recurrence-relations

Is there a nice simple formula for the following map:

$$\{1,2,3,4,5,6,\dots\} \mapsto \{1,2,1,2,1,2,\dots \}$$

Comment: $a_n =2-n \, mod (2)$

Comment: $\frac{(-1)^n+3}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

writing it as some regulations is easy but the formula wasn't that simple:
$$1+([-(n/2-[n/2)])$$
note: by [] I mean floor()

Answer (score 0):

Your sequence satisfies
$$a_n= \begin{cases}
1 &\text{if $n=1$},\\
2 &\text{if $n=2$},\\
a_{n-2} &\text{if $n\ge 3$}.
\end{cases}$$
The characteristic equation is $r^2-1=0$, yielding roots $r = \pm 1$.  So $a_n = A(1)^n+B(-1)^n$, and the initial conditions imply that
\begin{align}
1 &= A - B \\
2 &= A + B \\
\end{align}
Solving yields $A=3/2$ and $B=1/2$ and hence $a_n=(3+(-1)^n)/2$.